# How to get a range of rows(e.g. 1000th~2000th rows) with Apache Kudu?

Tags: apache-kudu

I'm using Apache Kudu for study, but how can I get a specific range of rows? For example, I want to get the 1000th to the 2000th rows.

I have found some client APIs about search bound with key:

```
 Status AddLowerBound(const KuduPartialRow& key);
 Status AddExclusiveUpperBound(const KuduPartialRow& key);
```

However, they are using `key` column bounds to filter rows, they do not using row range to select rows specificlly. Although I can do some scanning to add to the 1000th and 2000th rows, the next time I want the 1500th to the 3000th rows, I must scan again, it seems not a good solution.

So how can I solve it, Thanks:)